# Solution of $x_{k+1} = x_{k} (a x_{k} + b)$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Could anyone help me to solve the equation

$x_{k+1} = x_{k} (a x_{k} + b)$,

for find the explicit solution of $x_{k}$?

BTW. Do you know a GOOD book for the classification for non linear difference equation?
I've looked for something but most part speaks about the linear case, but i know there's some kind of classification like differential equation.

PS. i've fixed the mistake... sorry

Comment: is that $i$ or $k$ on the rhs?

Comment: $x_k=0$ satisfies that equation, but without any information on how $i$ relates to $k+1$ I don't think it's possible to say anything interesting.

Comment: Sorry... i miss the index the equation isn't $x_{k+1} = x_{i}(ax_{k} + b)$ but $x_{k+1} = x_{k}(ax_{k} + b)$, there isn't index $i$... sorry again

Comment: What makes you think there is an explicit solution?

Comment: There'are instances of this problem that provides explicit solutions,  if you set $a = -1$ and $b=2$ the equation has well known closed form solution.

Comment: Sure, there are some instances that have closed form solutions, but I think in general they don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html),

"A quadratic map is a quadratic recurrence equation of the form $x_{n+1}=a_2x_n^2+a_1x_n+a_0$.     While some quadratic maps are solvable in closed form (for example, the three solvable cases of the logistic map), most are not."

"The well-known recurrence $x_{n+1}=x_n^2+c$ that is often called "the" quadratic map is not in general solvable in closed form."

There is some discussion there of the few cases that do have closed form solutions.